# Integral, cylindrical coordinates and Gauss

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm stuck with a problem that is looking like this:

Use Gauss theorem to determine to flow of the vectorfield:

$z(ρ^{2}-1/ρ)e_ρ$

out of the region:

$x^{2} + y^{2} + (z-2)^{2} \leq 4$

I realize I have to calculate the undefined region first (that is along the z-axis), but how do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $e_{\rho}$?

Comment: Well, the question doesnt tell more than this, but I suppose my vectorfield is written in cylindrical coordinates and that is simply my unitvector, but please correct me if you think I'm wrong